# Teradata SQL: Max (greatest), 2nd and 3rd greatest column names

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with 6 columns in Teradata as follows:

```
ID   Feature1   Feature2   Feature3  Feature4  Feature5
1     12          15          1         22       350
2     121         0.9         999      756       879
...
```

I need to get the column names for the greatest, 2nd greatest and 3rd greatest values per row, so, I need output that looks like this:

```
ID   Greatest    2nd_Greatest   3rd_Greatest
1    Feature5     Feature4         Feature2
2    Feature3     Feature5         Feature4
```

Can someone help please.

Thank you!

Comment: 1. See normalisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a massive `case` statement, which gets even more complicated if any of the values are `NULL`.  That would be the fastest way, though.

The easiest method might be to unpivot the data and re-summarize it:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then feature end) as greatest_feature,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then feature end) as greatest_feature2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then feature end) as greatest_feature3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then which end) as which_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then which end) as which_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then which end) as which_3
from (select id, feature, row_number() over (partition by id order by feature desc) as serqnum
      from ((select id, feature1 as feature, 'feature1' as which from table) union all
            (select id, feature2 as feature, 'feature2' as which from table) union all
            (select id, feature3 as feature, 'feature3' as which from table) union all
            (select id, feature4 as feature, 'feature4' as which from table) union all
            (select id, feature5 as feature, 'feature5' as which from table) union all
            (select id, feature6 as feature, 'feature6' as which from table)
           ) t
      ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: Wow - this is some serious SQL! It got me half way - I am able to get, but ID, the VALUE of the greatest, 2nd greatest and 3rd greatest feature. But, I need the column names like in the 2nd table in my question.

Comment: @julian_b . .  You can also use column names instead of the values, if you like.

Comment: @julian_b The reason this query's so hideous is because your schema is denormalised. Fix that and your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, you're right. However, this is a modeling data set - I'm feeding this into an R model directly - that's why the table structure is really bad. At this point, it's a giant spreadsheet.

Comment: But surely you can feed it in from a view as easily as a table. So you have a normalised table from which you build a denormalised view - or something like that

Answer (score 2):

Refining Gordon's query:

Instead of several passes over the source table for those UNIONs you can create a list of features and then cross join it:

```
SELECT t.id, f.feature, 
   CASE f.feature
      WHEN 'feature1' THEN t.feature1
      WHEN 'feature2' THEN t.feature2    
      WHEN 'feature3' THEN t.feature3
      WHEN 'feature4' THEN t.feature4
      WHEN 'feature5' THEN t.feature5
   END AS val
FROM tab AS t CROSS JOIN 
 (
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'feature1' AS feature) AS dt 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'feature2' AS feature) AS dt 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'feature3' AS feature) AS dt 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'feature4' AS feature) AS dt 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'feature5' AS feature) AS dt 
  ) AS f
```

You can create the list on the fly like above using UNIONs or as a real table.

Starting with TD14.10 there's also a TD_UNPIVOT table operator (but still no PIVOT):

```
SELECT *
FROM TD_UNPIVOT
 (
   ON (SELECT id, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5 FROM tab)
   USING
      VALUE_COLUMNS('val')
      UNPIVOT_COLUMN('feature')
      COLUMN_LIST('feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5')
 ) AS dt
```

Also starting with TD14.10 there's LAST_VALUE which can be used for finding nth-greatest value together with the ROW_NUMBER, thus avoiding the final aggregation:

```
SELECT id, 
   feature AS "Greatest",
   LAST_VALUE(feature)
   OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val DESC
         ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS "2nd_Greatest",
   LAST_VALUE(feature)
   OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val DESC
         ROWS BETWEEN 2 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING) AS "3rd_Greatest"
FROM TD_UNPIVOT
 (
   ON (SELECT id, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5 FROM tab)
   USING
      VALUE_COLUMNS('val')
      UNPIVOT_COLUMN('feature')
      COLUMN_LIST('feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5')
 ) AS dt
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val DESC) = 1;
```

Comment: thank you for this. I went with Gordon's answer for my current version - saw this after all my code went to production. Thank you - I will refactor at a later time with your suggestion.